# Unable to import certificate to Mono store

Tags: c#, import, mono, certificate, client-certificates

I am trying to import certificate in mono store using below code. but it is not being imported into store and also not throwing any error.

```
          Mono.Security.X509.X509Store store1 = Mono.Security.X509.X509StoreManager.LocalMachine.TrustedRoot;
          Mono.Security.X509.X509Crl certCrl = new Mono.Security.X509.X509Crl(bytes);
          store1.Import(certCrl);
```

I am looking at the certificates at ~/.config/.mono/certs.

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Vibhu

Answer (score 0):

The source code is available, so you might check where the certificate goes,

https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/Mono.Security.X509/X509Store.cs

https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/Mono.Security.X509/X509StoreManager.cs

I don't think `Mono.Security.X509.X509StoreManager.LocalMachine.TrustedRoot` maps to `~/.config/.mono/certs`, as `X509StoreManager` shows another path `/usr/share/.mono/certs`.